# Expanding JTable Cell Dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable, and what I want to do is, everytime the user is editing a cell, i want that cell to expand, and when it loses focus, to return to normal size, is that possible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`TablePopupEditor`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513) is an appealing alternative.

Comment: Umm looks like it is, I could use a textarea for the cell but it still gets cropped so it would be pointless. Thanks!