# How can I get the coordinates of a cell in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, coordinates

I need the `x` and `y` coordinates of the table because I want to draw an object over the table. Is it possible to draw a canvas object over a table at all?

Comment: Do you just want an image tooltip, something  like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22246185/2587435)?

Comment: What do you mean by "canvas object"? Have you consider using the glass pane or JXLayer?

Comment: @MadProgrammer :-) `glass pane or JXLayer` ???= JViewport

Comment: @mkorbel without more context, it's difficult to suggest, but JXLayer could be made to fit over the JTabel...

Answer (score 4):

You can get the coordinates of a cell by calling:

```
Rectangle r = JTable.getCellRect(row, column, includeSpacing);
```