# JTable boolean values not updating when using JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, joptionpane

I'm trying to write a bit of code that can allow the user to fill in text fields by clicking on boolean cells in a `JTable`.

[image]

I can get the program to enter the data from the table into a text-field but my current method of doing this involves a JOptionPane which for some strange reason stops the table from changing the check-box values (i.e. the check-box doesn't change from black to ticked). Not only this but the selection doesn't update so the value in the last column remains false, even though the selection should switch it to true.

I think it might be something to do with the `JOptionPane` somehow overriding the selection event, but I don't know enough about the `JOptionPane` object to say how. My code is:

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
ListSelectionModel selectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
selectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();
        if (lsm.isSelectionEmpty()) {
            //no rows are selected do nothing
        } else {
            //First find the row clicked
            int selectedRow = lsm.getLeadSelectionIndex();
            /*
                * put a popup here to ask the user which peak to associate
                * the energy with.
                */
            System.out.println(selectedRow);
            //Get user to associate with a peak
            availablePeaks = getAvailablePeaks();
            String returnVal = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                null,
                "Select the peak:",
                "Peak Matching",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                null,
                availablePeaks, null);
            System.out.println(returnVal);
            //Determine the selection
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < availablePeaks.length; i++) {
                if (availablePeaks[i] == returnVal) {
                    index = i;
                } else {
                }
            }
            //Set the peak value in the peak specifier to the energy in the row
            double energy = (Double) table.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
            System.out.println(energy);
            frame.getPeakSetter().getPeakSpecifiers()[index].setEnergy(energy);
            frame.getPeakSetter().getPeakSpecifiers()[index].getTextField().setText("" + energy);
        }
    }
});
```

Does anyone know why a `JOptionPane` in the `ListSelectionListener` would stop the table from updating the check-boxes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your model returns `true` for `isCellEditable()` and that `getColumnClass()` returns `Boolean.class` for the `JCheckBox` column. This enables the default rednerer/editor, listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

It looks like the gesture of selecting the row is bringing up the dialog. It's not clear how this prevents the `DefaultCellEditor` from concluding; it works for me. As you are not checking `getValueIsAdjusting()`, I'm surprised you don't see two `ListSelectionEvent` instances.

In any case, bringing up a dialog each time the selection changes seems cumbersome. Several alternatives are possible:

- Keep the `ListSelectionListener`, make the cell non-editable by returning `false` from `isCellEditable()`, and set its value in the model only if the dialog concludes successfully.
- Drop the `ListSelectionListener` in favor of a `JButton` editor, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513).
- Drop the `ListSelectionListener` in favor of a custom `CellEditor`, as outlined below.

  ```
  table.setDefaultEditor(Boolean.class, new DefaultCellEditor(new JCheckBox()) {

      @Override
      public boolean stopCellEditing() {
          String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
          ...
          return super.stopCellEditing();
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I decided to keep the ListSelectionListener and made the cells in the final column non-editable. If the user clicks on the cell and a selection made the table now updates properly. :)