# Dynamically Increase JTable row height when editing, and decrease when finish edit

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

I am writing a small POS application, which shows a JTable with ticket information inside its cells. CellRenderer is a class which extends JPanel and implements TableCellRenderer, and contains a few JTextFields showing basic information (quantity, descripcion, price).
Also, I have another class extending JPanel and implementing TableCellEditor, which is used as CellEditor. This class contains more JTextFields and also a few jButtons.

What I need is simple: when I edit any cell by clicking with the mouse (or touching the screen, which is, as far as I know, the same event), dynamically increase the height of the cell I'm going to edit, so it can show all the components inside the editor. And when I finish editing, return cell height to its previous value.

Any idea about doing it?

Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: hmm ... agree with @mKorbel that jumpy rowHeights might get irritating for users. Would it be an option to only over-size (that is make it cover more area than its normal cell area) the editing component?

Answer (score 1):

> CellRenderer is a class which extends JPanel and implements TableCellRenderer, and contains a few JTextFields showing basic information (quantity, descripcion, price). Also, I have another class extending JPanel and implementing TableCellEditor, which is used as CellEditor. This class contains more JTextFields and also a few jButtons.

better could be to create popup window (`JDialog`) based on event from `JPopupMenu`,

> Dynamically Increase JTable row height when editing, and decrease when finish edit

don't confused users and wrong concept could be caused by jumping `JTables row` on the screen

> What I need is simple: when I edit any cell by clicking with the mouse (or touching the screen, which is, as far as I know, the same event), dynamically increase the height of the cell I'm going to edit, so it can show all the components inside the editor. And when I finish editing, return cell height to its previous value.

don't do that, but have to override, is possible by

- `DefaultCellEditor#setClickCountToStart(int)` for `TableCellEditor`
- `start`, `stop` and `cancelEdit` for `CellEditor`
- have to `notify` or `re_Layout` `JTable`, the same on `stop` and `cancelEdit`

Comment: Yes, a `CellEditor` will be required; also consider [`TablePopupEditor`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to how-to-adjust-rowHeights, but for an alternative mentioned in my comment: "oversize" the editorComponent only instead of updating the complete rowHeight (which I think would be too irritating to users, but up to you to decide, of course :)

```
// fake a bigger editing component
JTextField oversized = new JTextField() {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension dim = super.getPreferredSize();
        dim.height *= 5;
        return dim;
    }

};

TableCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(oversized);
JTable table = new JTable(new AncientSwingTeam()) {

    @Override
    public boolean editCellAt(int row, int column, EventObject e) {
        boolean result = super.editCellAt(row, column, e);
        if (result) {
            // adjust cell bounds of the editing component
            Rectangle bounds = getEditorComponent().getBounds();
            bounds.height = getEditorComponent().getPreferredSize().height;
            getEditorComponent().setBounds(bounds);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeEditor() {
        int editingColumn = getEditingColumn();
        super.removeEditor();
        if (editingColumn >= 0) {
            // cleanup
            repaint();
        }
    }


};
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(editor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try it, but I would say implementing [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html)'s `mouseClicked()` method is the way to go. Keep track of whether the cells height was already increased, and change the height accordingly.

Since `MouseListener` is an interface, `CellRenderer` could implement this interface too, keeping all cell-behavior in one class.

Comment: no, a mouseListener is not what you want: editing could be started by many means (including mouse, keyboard, programmatically ...)

Comment: The question stated "when I edit any cell by clicking with the mouse", so I figured this is the only case where this behavior is desired. Indeed, when *all* forms of editing need this behavior, a `MouseListener` is not the way to go.

Comment: welcome to the reality of fuzzy questions :-) Seriously: incomplete questions are no excuse for incomplete answers ... it's simply not an option in gui development to not consider (at least) mouse _and_ keyboard as user gestures.