# Double clicking on a table JButtton does not work and is just displaying class name of JButton

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` that just contains one item which is a `JButtton` that has an icon which is set to the `JFreeChart` generated chart.

If you click the button it launches a new window with the `JFreeChart` chart.

I have a cell renderer for the button which simply returns the `JButton` object that contains the chart item.

If I single click on the button it will launch the new window.

But if I double click on the button the new window launches, but the icon on the button, which used to be the `JFreeChart`, changes to just a text string with the class name path of the `JButton` with the class field values.

They other way I can get this  behavior to happen is if I remove the cell renderer then the `JButton` just diplays the class name.  So I'm not sure what is going on and have played around with it a ton and haven't made any progress. I was going to post some code but there is just too much of it.
If anybody has any ideas, I can post certain sections of code to help explain.
Here is code:

```
Class init {

    ...
    ItModel itModel = new ItModel ();
    JTable table = new JTable(itModel );
    TableRendrend rend = new TableRend();
    table.getColumn("it").setCellRenderer(rend);

}

class TableRend implements TableCellRenderer {
    JButton itButton;
    ...

    getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int columns){
         if(itButton ==null){
            itButton = new JButton (JButton)value.getIcon();
         }

        return itButton;

    }

}

Class itModel extends AbstractTableModel{
    JButton button;

...

public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, intColumnIndex){
     if(button==null){
        button = new JButton( new ImageIcon(JFreeChartImage.getImage()));
        }

    return button
    }

}
```

This all works except when double clicking on the JButton and it displays TEXT ex.

```
javax.Swing.JButton(0,0,...)
```

all field values instead of the the actual chart image that should be displayed

Comment: we cannot do anything without code

Comment: *"I can post certain sections of code to help explain."*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  *"Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"* 1) Leave out the noise 2) Fix that stuck '!' key.  BTW - do you have a question, and if so, what is it?

Comment: I just added a bunch of code to my original post,hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with the code you posted, and too long to include them all in a comment.

1. You should not store Swing components in the model. The creation of the components is the task for the renderer
2. I do not believe you can click the button which is returned by the renderer. That button is not contained in the `JTable` which is displayed. Only an image/screenshot/stamp of the button is drawn on-screen, but it does not behave like a button. You would need an editor for that. Consult the [`JTable` tutorial about the editors and renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more information

Comment: If I don't store the JButton in model what do I return from getValueAt()?? Somehow I have to return something??? Or should I not need a model and just have the rendere do it all?

Comment: @user565660: this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513) may be of interest.

Comment: Thank you very much for the resonses. I added a similar TableCellEditor and that seems to improve things. I don't really need to edit anything I just need the JButton to work for 2 clicks. I set the click count start to a very high value so it will never try to edit. Ex setClickCountToStart(Integer.Max). That seems to work for me. Thank you