# JTable: How to update cell using custom editor by pop-up input dialog box?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

I am learning from this [oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) that uses [TableDialogEditDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TableDialogEditDemo) example class

I wrote a custom cell Renderer and Editor for JTable.

I register them to this Oracle [TableDialogEditDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDialogEditDemoProject/src/components/TableDialogEditDemo.java) class

```
        ...
        ...
        //Set up renderer and editor for the Favorite Color column.
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Color.class,
                                 new ColorRenderer(true));
        table.setDefaultEditor(Color.class,
                               new ColorEditor());

        TableColumn c = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
        c.setCellRenderer(new CellStringRenderer()); //My custom Renderer
        c.setCellEditor(new CellStringEditor()); // My custom Editor

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
        ...
        ...
```

(**Updated description**)
When I click on a cell an input dialogue box pops up and that is OK, and when I type a text and click "OK" the cell in the JTable is updated, but text is not displayed/rendered correctly, I have to click on any other cell to make the text content displayed correctly in the cell.

What is the wrong with my code?.

My Renderer

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class CellStringRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer
{

    public CellStringRenderer()
    {
        this.setOpaque(true);
    }


    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
       String stringValue = (String) value;
       this.setText(stringValue);
       return this;
    }

}
```

My Editor (**Updated**)

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;


public class CellStringEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
        implements TableCellEditor
{

    String input;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
    {
        if (isSelected)
        {
            JOptionPane dialog = new JOptionPane();
            input = dialog.showInputDialog(null, "new value");
            return dialog;   
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue()
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you override the `TableModel.isCellEditable(int, int)` to return `true` for your column? Did you implement the `TableModel.setValueAt(int, int)` method to store your edited value?

Comment: Where's you table model?  As Stephan has pointed out, `TableModel#setValue` is responsible for making the requested changes to the model.

Comment: See also [`TablePopupEditor`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513).

Comment: @Stephan, @MadProgrammer  (I updated my question, because I almost solved it. if you can, answer the remaining unsolved point) The overriding for those methods  `TableModel.isCellEditable(int, int)` and `TableModel.setValueAt(int, int)` is already done in this oracle example [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDialogEditDemoProject/src/components/TableDialogEditDemo.java) to which I register my editor and renderer  to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am The author of this question, and I solved it. I will provide the solution so that others can get help from it.

I was trying to write a custom renderer and a custom editor to use with JTable.
The renderer simply uses JLabel to display data. It is already the standard component for JTable.
The editor is a dialogue box that appears when clicking on the cell that I want to edit.

Here is the solution:

The classes that will remain unchanged are the three classes from Oracle + my custom renderer class

1.[TableDialogEditDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDialogEditDemoProject/src/components/TableDialogEditDemo.java).

2.[ColorEditor.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDialogEditDemoProject/src/components/ColorEditor.java)

3.[ColorRenderer.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDialogEditDemoProject/src/components/ColorRenderer.java)

4.CellStringRenderer class provided above in the question body (my class)

The class that will be updated is the custom editor class (I changed its name from "CellStringEditor" to "DialogStringEditor"

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class DialogStringEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
        implements TableCellEditor,
        ActionListener
{

    String newInput;
    String oldValue;
    JButton button;
    static final String EDIT = "edit";

    public DialogStringEditor()
    {
        button = new JButton();
        button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        button.setActionCommand(EDIT);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (EDIT.equals(e.getActionCommand()))
        {
            newInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Edit", oldValue);
            if (newInput == null)
            {
                newInput = oldValue;
            }
            fireEditingStopped();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue()
    {
        return newInput;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean isSelected,
            int row,
            int column)
    {
        newInput = (String) value;
        oldValue = (String) value;
        return button;
    }
}
```

This will work ok

You can also make a little update for the renderer class "CellStringRenderer" to control how are selction and unselection colors of the cell appear.

update this method:

```
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        String stringValue = (String) value;
        this.setText(stringValue);

        if (isSelected)
        {
            this.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            this.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        } else
        {
            this.setBackground(table.getBackground());
            this.setForeground(table.getForeground());
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Regards.