# JTable: How to make a JComboBox cell renderer bigger than the rendered cell?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I am using this `JTable` method to create a Cell with a JComboBox as their rendered appearance.

```
public void addComboBoxToColumn(String[] options, int column_index){
    ComboTableCellRenderer renderer = new ComboTableCellRenderer();
    JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<String>(options);
    TableCellEditor combo_editor  = new DefaultCellEditor(combo);
    TableColumn column = getColumnModel().getColumn(column_index);
    column.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    column.setCellEditor(combo_editor);     
}
```

...

```
public class ComboTableCellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer, TableCellRenderer 
{
    DefaultListCellRenderer listRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer();
    DefaultTableCellRenderer tableRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

    private void configureRenderer(JLabel renderer, Object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
            renderer.setText((String)value);
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        listRenderer = (DefaultListCellRenderer)listRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        configureRenderer(listRenderer, value);
        return listRenderer;
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        tableRenderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer)tableRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        configureRenderer(tableRenderer, value);
        return tableRenderer;
    }

}
```

My problem is that the combobox is always the size of the cell. I do not want that. Is it possible to make the combo box bigger? Some options in the combobox are too big and are half-hidden.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: But if the column is _resizable_ then you can drag the column, isn't it?

Comment: it is resizable, but there are many columns in the table so that doesn't help very much.

Comment: @xpanta _Is it possible to make the combo box bigger?_ Bigger in the sense how much? Should it be the size of the text in it. Or does it have any specific size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that the combobox is always the size of the cell. I do
>   not want that. Is it possible to make the combo box bigger? Some
>   options in the combobox are too big and are half-hidden.

- not possible without jumping of cell `Dimmension` on the Screen, don't to confuse the user
- to avoiding possible side effects, I'd be
- create popup undecorated `JDialog` (for editable `JComboBox`), `JWindow`, put there `JComboBox`
- add `ListSelectionListener` (have to change `ListSelectionMode` to `SINGL`E)
- change built in `KeyBinding` in `JTable` for `TableCellEditor` (`double_click` or `F2`) to showing `JDialog`/`JWindow` have to center to the desired `Point` on the scren, `setVisible` must be wrapped in `invokeLater`
- add `ItemListener`, test for `SELECTED`, on selected to store value to (`setValueAt()`) `XxxTableModel`, then to hide `JDialog`/`JWindow`
- use only one `JDialog` (reuse by `removeAll` from content pane for another action from `GUI`) for whole `JVM` instance, only one for `JTable`

Comment: Something like this [`TablePopupEditor `](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513)?

Answer (score 1):

Override the [JTable.editCellAt](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JTable.java#JTable.editCellAt%28int,int%29). This is the method that positions the table cell editor by calling `setBounds` on it. Just set the bounds differently in your preferred way, maybe should span over several columns.