# How to place a JTextArea with JScrollPane inside the JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I placed the `JTextArea` with the `JScrollPane` inside the `JTable`, but using Key actions I can't edit the `JTextArea`.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question more, provide a code snippet of what you have actually programmed so far and provide a brief description of what you expect to see.

Comment: Try [`TablePopupEditor`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513) as an alternative.

Comment: Another to try: [MultiLineCellEditor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18165504/177145)

Comment: I tried it...Itz working..Thank You trashgod & aterai..