# How to create a jtable with different buttons in each row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have tried tutorial at http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2009/10/multiple-jbuttons-in-jtable-cell.html to produce the table below.

[image]

Now, i need to create a table with different buttons in each row. Please help me.

[image: table pattern]

Comment: No offence, but this is a really crappy way of doing this. Instead, you should either use a context popup menu or have two buttons outside of the table which react to the change in selection of the table. Apart from been easier to implement, it looks better

Comment: See [`TablePopupEditor`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513), for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess that [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) is what you are looking for:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public final class EnumSetTest {
  private JComponent makeUI() {
    String[] columnNames = {"REPORT ID", "ACTION"};
    Object[][] data = {
      {"Report1", EnumSet.of(Actions.PRINT)},
      {"Report2", EnumSet.of(Actions.PRINT, Actions.EDIT)},
      {"Report3", EnumSet.allOf(Actions.class)},
      {"Report4", EnumSet.of(Actions.PRINT)}
    };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
      @Override public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
      }
    };
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    table.setRowHeight(36);
    TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    column.setCellRenderer(new ButtonsRenderer());
    column.setCellEditor(new ButtonsEditor(table));
    return new JScrollPane(table);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new EnumSetTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

enum Actions { PRINT, EDIT; }

class ButtonsPanel extends JPanel {
  public final List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
  public ButtonsPanel() {
    super(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    setOpaque(true);
    for (Actions a : Actions.values()) {
      JButton b = new JButton(a.toString());
      b.setFocusable(false);
      b.setRolloverEnabled(false);
      add(b);
      buttons.add(b);
    }
  }
  protected void updateButtons(Object value) {
    if (value instanceof EnumSet) {
      EnumSet ea = (EnumSet) value;
      removeAll();
      if (ea.contains(Actions.PRINT)) {
        add(buttons.get(0));
      }
      if (ea.contains(Actions.EDIT)) {
        add(buttons.get(1));
      }
    }
  }
}

class ButtonsRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
  private final ButtonsPanel panel = new ButtonsPanel();
  @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
      JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    panel.setBackground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground());
    panel.updateButtons(value);
    return panel;
  }
}

class PrintAction extends AbstractAction {
  private final JTable table;
  public PrintAction(JTable table) {
    super(Actions.PRINT.toString());
    this.table = table;
  }
  @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(table, "Printing");
  }
}

class EditAction extends AbstractAction {
  private final JTable table;
  public EditAction(JTable table) {
    super(Actions.EDIT.toString());
    this.table = table;
  }
  @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int row = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getEditingRow());
    Object o = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(table, "Editing: " + o);
  }
}

class ButtonsEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
  private final ButtonsPanel panel = new ButtonsPanel();
  private final JTable table;
  private Object o;
  private class EditingStopHandler extends MouseAdapter implements ActionListener {
    @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      Object o = e.getSource();
      if (o instanceof TableCellEditor) {
        actionPerformed(null);
      } else if (o instanceof JButton) {
        ButtonModel m = ((JButton) e.getComponent()).getModel();
        if (m.isPressed() && table.isRowSelected(table.getEditingRow()) && e.isControlDown()) {
          panel.setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
      }
    }
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
          fireEditingStopped();
        }
      });
    }
  }
  public ButtonsEditor(JTable table) {
    super();
    this.table = table;
    panel.buttons.get(0).setAction(new PrintAction(table));
    panel.buttons.get(1).setAction(new EditAction(table));

    EditingStopHandler handler = new EditingStopHandler();
    for (JButton b : panel.buttons) {
      b.addMouseListener(handler);
      b.addActionListener(handler);
    }
    panel.addMouseListener(handler);
  }
  @Override public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
      JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    panel.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    panel.updateButtons(value);
    o = value;
    return panel;
  }
  @Override public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return o;
  }
}
```