# Changing enter and tab key events from a TextArea rendered in a Table at Java Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm using a renderer to make a `JTable` in Java NetBeans with multiple rows in a cell (Line Wrapping).
What I need to do, is that the user be able do some format to the cell, like Tab's and Enter's in the Text, when you use a Text Area without render, it does it like the way I want, it doesn't move between other controllers with this key events, the problem is when it gets rendered, if you press Enter, its like an accept event, and tab moves between controls. I think that there's still some properties that should be configured at the renderer for the text area component.

Here's the code I'm using for the rendering:

```
public class TableCellLongTextRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer{  
   @Override 
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {  
        this.setText((String)value);  
        this.setWrapStyleWord(true);                      
        this.setLineWrap(true);      
        this.setRows(10);


        //set the JTextArea to the width of the table column  
        setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(),getPreferredSize().height);  
        if (table.getRowHeight(row) != getPreferredSize().height) {  
            //set the height of the table row to the calculated height of the JTextArea  
            table.setRowHeight(row, getPreferredSize().height);  
        }  
        return this;  
    }
}
```

And here's how I use it:

```
table1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(
         new FAgregarArticulos.TableCellLongTextRenderer ());
```

Comment: Don't change the state of the tabLe from the renderer. The size of the cell will be set by the table

Comment: Also consider [`TablePopupEditor`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513).