# How to make a multiline cell in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, rows

I wanted to know if there is a way to do this in a table with Java Swing.

[image: Image for Example]

I'm working with tables using `Vector<Vector<String>>` for passing each column data in a DefaultTableModel Object, but for this I don't know what I have to use.

Note: The table data is added dynamically during runtime.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.crionics.com/public/swing_examples/SwingExamples.html), see the section on tables.  Now note, this is rather old and the table API has changed, so some of this might not work or might need to some modifications to work properly

Comment: Also consider [`TablePopupEditor`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use customized `TabelCellRenderer` with `JList` view. Following code should work.

```
public class VectorTableCellRenderer extends JList<String> implements TableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (value instanceof Vector) {
            setListData((Vector) value);
        }

        if (isSelected) {
            setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.selectionBackground"));
        } else {
            setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.background"));
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: How to use VectorTableCellRenderer**

```
    VectorTableCellRenderer renderer = new VectorTableCellRenderer();

    //set TableCellRenderer into a specified JTable column class
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Vector.class, renderer);

    //or, set TableCellRenderer into a specified JTable column
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

This is my tested output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But sorry for the ignorance, but how can I use it? I've already add it to my code, but I don't know how to "activate" it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, and for adding different items to different rows? I got it working, but every row has the same items. I'd like to do something like your example. Sorry if this is trivial, I'm pretty noob. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is, just waiting the answer for my last question to mark it as accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90666/discussion-between-guolf3377-and-channa-jayamuni).

Answer (score 0):

```
javax.swing.JTable jTableReport = new javax.swing.JTable();// new JTable
javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel TableModel = new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(ArrayListTable.size(),Header.length);//new TableModel
//Now you must be add your data inside TableModel
    jTableReport.setModel(TableModel);//setModel inside JTable

int RowWidth = 90;//Width You want to be
int RowHight = 25;//Hight of one line

for (int C = 0; C < jTableReport.getColumnCount(); C++) {
    for (int R = 0; R < jTableReport.getRowCount(); R++) {
        Object RowValue = jTableReport.getValueAt(R, C);
        int lengthRow = String.valueOf(RowValue).length();
        if (lengthRow>RowWidth) {
            int NumLines = lengthRow/RowWidth;
                    if (NumLines == 1) {
                        NumLines = 2;
                    }
            int begainIndex = 0;
            int endIndex = RowWidth;
            String NewRowValue = String.valueOf(RowValue);
            for (int i = 1; i < NumLines; i++) {
                if (i==1) {
                    NewRowValue = "<html>"+(String.valueOf(RowValue).substring(begainIndex, endIndex))+"<br>";
                }else if (i == NumLines) {
                    NewRowValue = NewRowValue + (String.valueOf(RowValue).substring(begainIndex, endIndex))+"</html>";
                }else {
                    NewRowValue = NewRowValue + (String.valueOf(RowValue).substring(begainIndex, endIndex))+"<br>";
                }

                begainIndex = begainIndex + RowWidth;
                endIndex = endIndex + RowWidth;
                i++;
            }
            jTableReport.setValueAt(NewRowValue, R, C);
            jTableReport.setRowHeight(R, NumLines*RowHight);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not encouraged. Please add some comment to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void resizeCellWidthAndHieght(JTable table, int HorizontalAlignment, int VerticalAlignment) {
    DefaultTableCellRenderer defaultTableCellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        defaultTableCellRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment);
        defaultTableCellRenderer.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(table.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    final TableColumnModel columnmodel = table.getColumnModel();
    int HieghtArray[] = new int[table.getRowCount()] ;
    for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setCellRenderer(defaultTableCellRenderer);
        int width = 15; // Min width
        int height = 25; // Min width
        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
            TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
            Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
            width = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width +1 , width);
            height = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().height +4 , HieghtArray[row]);
            if (HieghtArray[row]< height) {
                HieghtArray[row] = height;
            }

        }
        if(width > 300)
            width=300;
        columnmodel.getColumn(column).setPreferredWidth(width);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
        try {
            table.setRowHeight(i, HieghtArray[i]);
        } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
}
```