# Force JTable row selection if clicking outside visible JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpopupmenu

I have added a `JPopupMenu` to a `JTable` with `setComponentPopupMenu`. The problem is that while the `JPopupMenu` is open/visible, when I left-click on a row outside the popup menu, the menu closes but the row is not selected so I have to click again on it to highlight it. Is there any way to fix that?

**EDIT**

I've added sample code.

By the way this behavior occurs only in Windows LaF. I've just tested it and it appears that the default Java LaF allows for left-click row selection while the JPopupMenu is open.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;

public class TableSTACK {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        String[] headers = {"Column 1", "Column 2"};

        Object[][] data = { {"Row",   "1"}, {"Row",   "2"},
                {"Row",   "3"}, {"Row",   "4"}, {"Row",   "5"},
                {"Row",   "6"}, {"Row",   "7"}, {"Row",   "8"}, };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, headers);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());        

        final JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem();
        item1.setText("Menu Item 1");       
        final JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem();
        item2.setText("Menu Item 2");
        final JMenuItem item3 = new JMenuItem();
        item3.setText("Menu Item 3");

        final JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        popupMenu.add(item1);
        popupMenu.addSeparator();
        popupMenu.add(item2);
        popupMenu.add(item3);
        table.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);

        popupMenu.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {
            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // force selection of row upon right-click (it works)
                        int rowAtPoint = table.rowAtPoint(SwingUtilities.convertPoint(popupMenu, new Point(0, 0), table));
                        if (rowAtPoint > -1) {
                            table.setRowSelectionInterval(rowAtPoint, rowAtPoint);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // force row selection upon exiting popup menu
                        // does not work; rowAtPoint always returns -1
                        int rowAtPoint = table.rowAtPoint(SwingUtilities.convertPoint(null, new Point(0, 0), table));
                        //int rowAtPoint = table.rowAtPoint(SwingUtilities.convertPoint(popupMenu, new Point(0, 0), table));
                        if (rowAtPoint > -1) {
                            table.setRowSelectionInterval(rowAtPoint, rowAtPoint);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                // TODO
            }
        });


        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15));
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, gbc);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a cell editor like [`TablePopupEditor`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513). If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: This was originally closed as a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590897/jtable-design-to-synchronize-with-back-end-data-structure. I don't think this question is about a popup editor. The question is about using a "JPopupMenu" and clicking on the table when the menu is open. I reopened the question.

Comment: I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a LAF issue.

It works for me when I use the default LAF but doesn't work when I use the platform LAF, which for me is Windows.

A potential solution on Windows is to use a `MouseListener` to select the line. Note the code is added to the `mouseReleased` event. For some reason the table does not receive the `mousePressed` event even though according to the `AWTEventListener` the table is the source of the `mousePressed` event.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TablePopupListener extends JPanel
{
    public TablePopupListener()
    {
        JTable table = new JTable(10, 5);
        add( new JScrollPane( table ) );

        JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        popup.add( new JMenuItem("Do Something1") );
        popup.add( new JMenuItem("Do Something2") );

        table.setComponentPopupMenu( popup );

        table.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Pressed JTable");
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Released JTable");

                int row = table.rowAtPoint( e.getPoint() );

                if (row != -1
                && !table.isRowSelected(row))
                {
                   table.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println(ex); }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TablePopupListener");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TablePopupListener());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener( new AWTEventListener()
        {
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e)
            {
                String event = null;

                switch (e.getID())
                {
                    case MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED:  event = "Pressed: " ; break;
                    case MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED:  event = "Released: " ; break;
                    case MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED:  event = "Entered: " ; break;
                    case MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED:  event = "Exited: " ; break;
                    default: event = null; break;
                }

                if (event != null)
                {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println(event + e.getSource().getClass());
                }
            }
        },  AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Comment: So I guess I'll keep the `PopupMenuListener` for forcing table row selection upon right-click and I'll add a `MouseListener` to force row selection upon left-click while the `JPopupMenu` is visible. Too bad it has to be that complex... Thanks